# Angular 6 - search complex object inside list and get name from lookup table

Tags: typescript

I want to search list of complex object.

My list looks like:

```
  private employees: Employee[] = [
    {
      name: 'Mary Jay',
      departmentsList: [1, 2, 3], //those are Id-s of departments from the list below
      emailList: [ 'emp1@gamil.com', 'emp2@gmail.com', 'emp3@gmail.com' ]
    }
  ];


   private departments: Department[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'dep1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'dep2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'dep3' },
    { id: 4, name: 'dep4' },
    { id: 5, name: 'dep5' },
    { id: 6, name: 'dep6' }
  ];
```

What I want to achieve is to implement search filter by department name and email.

Does anyone have the idea how to get department name from lookup table iterting through this list of complex objects? Using this I would be able to search throug list of emails and list of departments using their names.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the end goal here? Do you just want to display the associated departments in a component or something else?

Comment: I want to be able to search  employee by department name and email. I have list of emails and the list of departments id-s. In order to search departments I want to reach their names.

Comment: You can do that with [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). Give it a shot yourself and see if you can figure it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try and post it :)

Comment: @Igor, I write it on this way: employees.forEach(emp => { emp.departmentsList.forEach(dep => 
       departments.filter(n => { if(dep==n.id)) { return n.name;}}))}); As you can see I search through employeeList to get departments id and than from departments list I found  name by matching Id from  employeeList :)

Answer (score 0):

```
departments = [
{ id: 1, name: 'dep1' },
{ id: 2, name: 'dep2' },
{ id: 3, name: 'dep3' },
{ id: 4, name: 'dep4' },
{ id: 5, name: 'dep5' },
{ id: 6, name: 'dep6' }
]
const valueFromInput = 'dep';
const allDepartmentNames = departments.map(department => department.name);
const result = allDepartmentNames.filter(name => name.includes(valueFromInput));



console.log(result)
```